# What is the difference between return and expected return?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, comparison, q-learning, return, expectation

At a time step $t$, for a state $S_{t}$, the return is defined as the discounted cumulative reward from that time step $t$.

If an agent is following a policy (which in itself is a probability distribution of choosing a next state $S_{t+1}$ from $S_{t}$), the agent wants to find the value at $S_{t}$ by calculating sort of "weighted average" of all the returns from $S_{t}.$ This is called the expected return.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

Formally, the **return** (also known as the *cumulative future discounted reward*) can be defined as

$$
G_t = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \gamma^k R_{t+k+1},
$$

where $0 \leq \gamma \leq 1$ is the discount factor and $R_{i}$ is the reward at time step $i$. Here $G_t$ and $R_i$ are considered random variables (and r.v.s are usually denoted with capital letters, so I am using the notation used in the book [Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction](http://incompleteideas.net/book/bookdraft2017nov5.pdf), **2nd edition**).

The **expected return** is defined as

\begin{align}
v^\pi(s) 
&= \mathbb{E}\left[G_t \mid S_t = s \right] \\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{k=0}^\infty \gamma^k R_{t+k+1} \bigm\vert S_t = s \right]
\end{align}

In other words, the value of a state $s$ (associated with a policy $\pi$) is equal to the expectation of the return $G_t$ given that $S_t = s$, so $v^\pi(s)$ is defined as a [conditional expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation). Note also that the expected value is usually defined with respect to a random variable, which is the case. Note also that $S_t$ is a random variable, while $s$ is a realization of this random variable.

A policy is **not** a probability distribution of choosing the next state. A stochastic policy is a family of a conditional probability distribution *over actions given states*. There are also deterministic policies. Have a look at this question [What is the difference between a stochastic and a deterministic policy?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/12274/2444) for more details about the definition of stochastic and deterministic policies.

> If an agent is following a policy, the agent wants to find the value at $S_{t}$ by calculating a sort of "weighted average" of all the returns from $S_{t}.$ This is called the expected return.

In the case of Monte Carlo Prediction, the value of a state associated with a specific policy, that is, the expected value of the return given a state is approximated with a finite (weighted) average. See e.g. [What is the difference between First-Visit Monte-Carlo and Every-Visit Monte-Carlo Policy Evaluation?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/10818/2444). Furthermore, note that the [expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) of a *discrete* random variable is defined as a weighted average.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, the return is the discounted future reward from the one iteration while the expected return is averaged over a bunch of iterations.